# Block wrapping DIV disable with theme hook?

Tags: theming, hooks

I've managed to suppress the wrapping markup for a few blocks using

block--block--1.tpl.php
region--banner.tpl.php

but now it's getting messy as I have several blocks which require no additional wrpaping markup so I would ideally like to do this in a theme function with a switch case...but can't find any example that works...

function front_preprocess_block(&$vars, $hook) {

```
$to_delete = array('block-block-4');

//if(in_array($vars['block']->delta , $to_delete)) {
//  $vars['template_files'][0] = 'block-empty'; 
//}

print_r($vars);
```

}

I need to remove wrppaing DIV's for about 4 blocks onlys...ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an additional variable in `hook_preprocess_block()` and check for that variable in `block.tpl.php file`, example:

```
function front_preprocess_block(&$vars, $hook) {
  //dpm($vars);
  $vars['must_be_removed'] = FALSE;
  if(/* CONDITION e.g. $vars['elements']['#block']->delta == 'MY_BLOCK_DELTA' */) {
    $vars['must_be_removed'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

and `block.tpl.php` file;

```
<?php if($must_be_removed): ?>
  <?php print $content ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if ($block->subject): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><span><?php print $block->subject ?></span></h2>
<?php endif;?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php print $content ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ohhh...so I can't stub out the markup just from a function but rather use the catch-all block.tpl.php and conditional tests...OK that works :) thank you kindly

Comment: @Alex.Barylski I'm glad if I could help you..